# Format data as a resultset, array of hashtables not doing the job

Tags: powershell

I have an array of hashtables that I want to view in a gridview however its not presenting as i'd like. I want every key to become a column, but that's not what's happening
The question might better be phrased as, how do I get this to output a grid with 2 rows and 3 columns rather than 6 rows and 2 columns:

```
@(
    @{"Name"="jack";"Age"="20";"Gender"="M"},
    @{"Name"="jill";"Age"="20";"Gender"="F"}
) | Out-GridView
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, this seems to do it (uses Calculated Properties), but I'm sure there must be a cleaner way of doing this, no?

```
@(
    @{"Name"="jack";"Age"="20";"Gender"="M"},
    @{"Name"="jill";"Age"="20";"Gender"="F"}
) | select @{Name="Name";Expression={$_["Name"]}},@{Name="Age";Expression={$_["Age"]}},@{Name="Gender";Expression={$_["Gender"]}} | Out-GridView
```

[image]

Comment: `% { New-Object PSObject -Property $_ }` or v3+ `% { [PSCustomObject]$_.PSObject.BaseObject }` or v5+ `% { [PSCustomObject]$_ }`.

Comment: Oh fantastic, thank you very much. Not on v5 yet but very much looking forward to that.